# iOS GeoFencing Loiter/Delay Solution

Tags: objective-c, ios7, core-location, background-process, geofencing

I am currently working on an issue as I am trying to figure out an implementation for GeoFencing w/ Loitering in iOS.

Everything I have done so far works fantastically for GeoFencing while the Application is foregrounded.

My steps taken are as follows:

1. On Location Manager didUpdateLocations go ahead and download in the background new GeoFences.
2. Upon receiving the background fetch, parse through my array of currently assigned geoFences and add/remove as needed due to said 20 limit, I just basically remove the farthest from my current location out of ones that need to be added from the web call.
3. Once I'm done and the dust settles upon what Geo's needed to be removed/added. I assign the regions that are new to be monitored.
4. Whenever I receive a enter/exit call from the location delegate I look at the trigger and my data set to see what kind of GeoFence I am dealing with. My problem stems from dealing with Loitering GeoFences (as in, when someone spends 5 minutes in this region after entering then it was a fully "successful" trigger.

When the application is foregrounded I simply create a UILocalNotification with a UserInfo dictionary that contains most of the data I need to figure out the GeoFence and recreate the region (if the user is still within the region -> Success!), I then set it to fire with a date of now+delayTimeInSeconds. This works fantastically without error.

My issue is that the LocalNotification approach does not work when the Application is backgrounded as the LocalNotification does not have AlertBody and is meant to not alert the user in any way or for, as this notification is essentially a soft trigger. The hard alert that alerts the user is done once we have determined if the user is still within the GeoFence (or is leaving the GeoFence).

I am brainstorming different solutions on how to deal with this issue and if anyone has some insight it'd be quite helpful.

My current idea is to create a background task with a duration equal to the maximum duration of whatever current GeoFence Loiter time periods I have (as long as it does not exceed 10 minutes) and kick the location services to being in normal mode. Find the current location and for each time period necessary trigger off a location check for a trigger. If there is a trigger go ahead and show the notification to the user. Continue until I'm out of time/out of Loiter GeoFences and exit out early if possible.

Of course this would be fine if LocalNotifications sent in the background without an alert would wake up the Application, unfortunately not :X